# GWT - IE not downloading external scripts included in UiBinder

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt, uibinder, external-script

I have some external Javascript files in my GWT app that I only want to download when the user accesses the section that requires them. I included the JS files in a UiBinder page like so:

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <script src="blah.js"/>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

The files won't necessarily be downloaded as soon as the view is loaded, so when I load the view, I check for an exception indicating that the external code isn't accessible and try again until the view can be created without an exception.

This works in Firefox but it doesn't work in IE7/IE8. I used AJAX Edition to trace what's happening in IE, and a request for the file is made but it doesn't download anything, the size is 0. The web server access logs don't show that the file was requested.

Any idea what's going on?

Or is there a better way to do this? The investigating I've done thus far does not indicate that GWT has a convenient way to do this.

**Update:**

Although we're not on 2.4 yet, just to try I copied in the source files needed for ScriptInjector and attempted to use that per the suggestion by Thomas. The JS files download correctly in both browsers, but I get the '$wnd.xxxx is undefined' exception indicating that the references in the external script can't be found. I don't try to load my widget until the onSuccess() call returns from the script inject - so my code looks something like this:

```
ScriptInjector.fromUrl("../xxxx.js").setCallback( 
      new Callback<Void, Exception>() { 
         public void onFailure(Exception reason) { 
           Window.alert("Script load failed."); 
         } 
         public void onSuccess(Void result) { 
           Window.alert("Script load success."); 
           MyWidget widget = new MyWidget(); 
           client.onSuccess(widget); // adds the widget to the view 
         } 
      }).inject();
```

I also don't see the JS file references added to the DOM in Firebug, but I wonder if that is because they are being added to the DOM of the GWT portion of the page, not to the actual index.jsp.

Comment: It seems like GWT is doing its job and getting the script requested, but that IE or your server is not downloading it.  GWT doesn't have any functionality to make sure that the DOM is interpreted correctly, so I think you'll have to look outside GWT for this one.

Comment: By "external" do you mean they are not hosted in your application? Like jQuery hosted by Google, for example?

Comment: It is hosted in the app, I meant more that I did not write it and don't maintain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to tell the ScriptInjector to add the script to the top level window.

```
ScriptInjector.fromUrl(scriptUrl)
    .setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW)
    .setCallback(new Callback<Void, Exception>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void result) {
            //script loaded OK
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception reason) {
            //TODO script injection failed
        }
    }).inject();
```

Answer (score 1):

Script elements inserted using `innerHTML` (which is what `HTMLPanel` uses) are not executed.

You'll have to use [`ScriptInjector`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/ScriptInjector.html) to dynamically inject a script into your page.

Comment: ScriptInjector isn't an option just yet, we aren't at 2.4. This points me in a useful direction though, I looked up some info on the innerHTML quirks, and it looks like there may be a hack or two I can try.

Comment: I tried ScriptInjector anyway, and a couple hacks, I got the files to download in both browsers. But either way I did it my widget doesn't seem to recognize the external script now (see updates to the question).